# Print PDF from C# using pdfium to roll paper

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to print from a pdf file  which has been generated to replicate a 80mm wide roll printout. Ie the pdf is printed to a custom 80mm wide page type.

I send this file using the code below, it is passed a papername of 80 x 297mm which corresponds to a physical thermal printer paper size. I cannot work out why pdfiumviewer is making the output on the printer scaled down to only being about 20mm wide on the 80mm wide paper When I print the PDF directly from EDGE ot adobe the pdf fits perfectly on the paper. I cannot work out why it is scaling down.

If anyone has a solution or a better way to print PDF silently to a destination printer I am very open to suggestions.

```
public bool PrintPDF(string printer, string paperName, string filename, int copies)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the printer settings for our printer
        var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
        {
            PrinterName = printer,
            Copies = (short)copies,
        };
        // Create our page settings for the paper size selected
        var pageSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings)
        
  
        {
            Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),
        };
        foreach (PaperSize papersize in printerSettings.PaperSizes)
        {
            if (papersize.PaperName == paperName)
            {
                pageSettings.PaperSize = papersize;
                break;
            }
        }

    
       // Now print the PDF document
        using (var document = PdfDocument.Load(filename))
        {
            using (var printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
            {
                printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
                printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
               

                printDocument.Print();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `printDocument.OriginAtMargins = true;`

Comment: I sorted out the issue with the scaled too smal image, the length of the document was being scaled to fit. But now I have the pdf document being cut off by hard margins ie the job is printing outside the printable area, I cannot work out why the printdocument object is not getting scaled to fit inside the printable area any help appreciated.